# Bash : Curl grep result as string variable

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash script as below:

```
curl -s "$url" | grep "https://cdn" | tail -n 1 | awk -F[\",] '{print $2}'
```

which is working fine, when i run run it, i able to get the cdn url as:

```
https://cdn.some-domain.com/some-result/
```

when i put it as variable :

```
myvariable=$(curl -s "$url" | grep "https://cdn" | tail -n 1 | awk -F[\",] '{print $2}')
```

and i echo it like this:

```
echo "CDN URL:  '$myvariable'"
```

i get blank result. CDN URL:

any idea what could be wrong? thanks

Comment: A common problem is that some HTTP APIs output DOS line endings, though I don't see how you could get _exactly_ the output you claim because of that. (But then your diagnostics don't seem particularly exact.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `curl` command produces a trailing DOS carriage return, that will botch the output, though not exactly like you describe. Still, maybe try this.

```
myvariable=$(curl -s "$url" | awk -F[\",] '/https:\/\/cdn/{ sub(/\r/, ""); url=$2} END { print url }')
```

Notice also how I refactored the `grep` and the `tail` (and now also `tr -d '\r'`) into the Awk command. Tangentially, see [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: you are right, the ^M character cause it become invalid url for CURL, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The result could be blank if there's only one item after `awk`'s split.
You might try `grep -o` to only return the matched string:

```sh
myvariable=$(curl -s "$url" | grep -oP 'https://cdn.*?[",].*' | tail -n 1 | awk -F[\",] '{print $2}')
echo "$myvariable"
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but your regex seems frightfully wrong for what you are suggesting. Also, switching from proper modern `$(...)` command-substitution syntax to obsolescent backticks seems like a move in the wrong direction. Finally, you should [quote your shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).